# Can't display method Word counter

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms

I'm trying to create a method to pass a string to the method, and then I want to display the number of words in the string. The string being the user input from the textbox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   countMethod();

}
private string countMethod()
{
    String text = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    int wordCount = 0, index = 0;

    while (index < text.Length)
    {
        // check if current char is part of a word
        while (index < text.Length && Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]) == false)
            index++;

        wordCount++;

        // skip whitespace until next word
        while (index < text.Length && Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]) == true)
            index++;
    }
    return MessageBox.Show(wordCount.ToString());
}
```

EDIT:

I added an argument to the method. And send the wordCount to a string, once the loop was done. I tried it several times and it works. I'm new to programming, and is there a reason why this wouldn't work or should do it another way? Thanks

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string userInput = textBox1.Text;
   countMethod(userInput);


}
private string countMethod(string input)
{
    string text = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    int wordCount = 0, index = 0;

    while (index < text.Length)
    {
        // check if current char is part of a word
        while (index < text.Length && Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]) == false)
            index++;

        wordCount++;

        // skip whitespace until next word
        while (index < text.Length && Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]) == true)
            index++;
    }
    string total = wordCount.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("The total words in this string are: " +total);
    return total;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: `return MessageBox.Show`.....first time I've ever seen a `MessgeBox` returned from a method.  Usually either the method displays the message box or returns a value that is displayed in the message box by the calling method.

Comment: Tim, that was a mistake, I fixed it.

Comment: how do I post the new code that I have, it only allows certain amount of characters

Comment: @Sam Click the Edit button.

Comment: Using extension method is also good idea.

Comment: You should not edit your question to ask a new one. If you find the answer to this question then click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Then create a new question and ask other problems you faced in it. @sam

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way to do it!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var wordCount = CountWords(textBox1.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(wordCount.ToString());

}
private int CountWords(string input)
{
    var separators = new[] { ' ', '.' };
    var count = input.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    return count;
}
```

Add/Remove the separators you want to/from the `separators` array.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use extension method. It's good idea.

```
public static class MyExtentionClass
{
    public static int WordCount(this string str)
    {
        var separators = new[] { ' ', '.', ',' };
        var count = str.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;

        return count;
    }
}
```

eg:

```
MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text.WordCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on white spaces then get the count

```
int wordCount = textBox1.Text.Trim().Split(" ").Count;
```